# Python parallel threads in 3.13 GIL-less environment

Tags: python, multithreading, cpython, gil

I was working on a python program and I was attempting to implement some parallel processing to improve the runtime for a cpu-bound task that don't write to the same memory location. I've had some experience with using the `multiprocessing` library since using `threading` in past projects ran slower due to the GIL. From my understanding the GIL was removed in 3.13. Does this mean the `threading` module should work faster than `multiprocessing` for my use-case now by default without any of the GIL workarounds? If this is not the case, are there any libraries that have been developed for the non-GIL 3.13 that I can use for multithreading?

I tried looking at the PEPs for 3.13 and the removing of GIL (703), but I'm not totally able to understand how it affects existing libraries.

Comment: Python 3.13's anticipated release is still a year away. Anything can change between now and then, so I don't think this question can be meaningfully answered yet.

Comment: Do not that AFAIK removing the GIL from CPython is not yet planned, for 3.13 or otherwise. All that is currently planned for 3.13 is to add an experimental build flag for compiling CPython without a GIL.

Comment: My bad, I guess my question is more so just about using Alpha 1. Does single-threaded code need to modified to run with GIL-disabled? In the same ljne of thought, if I run a multi-threaded program on a cpython build that has GIL disabled, can I expect it to just run faster?

Comment: Python docs are quite clear about compatibility between versions.  If your code uses the Limited C API, it will work without re-compilation between 3.12 and 3.13. If your code uses the Public API, then it will be source compatible, but may require compilation.  But again, it's way too early to know how the GIL-less environment will work or perform.

Answer (score 1):

Removal of GIL is a slow and multi-release schedule. There will most likely be 2 releases of Python (with/without GIL enabled out of the box) while they roll out the fixes required like immortal objects (which is in 3.12), changes to reference counting, etc. If you need to bypass GIL and you're worried about performance, read up on Cython. It allows creating fast C++ extensions AND lets you bypass the GIL as long as you're working with things like memory views (Python objects can't be accessed when you release the GIL).